# Convert Json to Custom Data Type List in Dart

Tags: json, flutter, flutterflow

I am trying to parse my REST API output in Flutterflow with a custom flutter function.
My JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "markers": [
    {
      "entityId": 123
      "lat": 10.32,
      "lng": 9.32
    },
    {
      "entityId": 124
      "lat": 11.32,
      "lng": 8.32
    }
  ],
  "config": ...
}
```

And my custom function in Flutter looks like this:

```
List<MapLocationStruct>? createLocationsFromJson(dynamic jsonMarkers) {
  /// MODIFY CODE ONLY BELOW THIS LINE

  List<MapLocationStruct> locations = [];
  dynamic markers = jsonDecode(jsonMarkers['markers']);
  markers.forEach((element) {
    MapLocationStruct location = new MapLocationStruct(
        entityId: element['entity_id'],
        latLng: new LatLng(element['lat'], element['ng']));
    locations.add(location);
  });
  return locations;

  /// MODIFY CODE ONLY ABOVE THIS LINE
}
```

No matter what I try, I always get errors, when I test the function. How can I parse the json correctly in flutter(flow)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `jsonMarkers` is the JSON string you shouldn't do

```
dynamic markers = jsonDecode(jsonMarkers['markers']);
```

but

```
dynamic markers = jsonDecode(jsonMarkers)['markers'];
```

but `jsonMarkers` being dynamic probably means that it already is decoded, so you could do

```
dynamic markers = jsonMarkers['markers'];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, then the error changes to: TypeError: Instance of 'JsLinkedHashMap<String, Object>': type 'JsLinkedHashMap<String, Object>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: @Abenil then I guess `jsonMarkers` is already jsonDecoded. then it's simply `dynamic markers = jsonMarkers['markers'];`

Comment: Now I feel like an idiot. Thank you so much. It seems like Flutterflow is really already decoding the JSON string. That's why the function parameter type is dynamic even though I picked JSON in Flutterflow. Now it all makes sense. Thank you so much again. If you post it as reply, I will accept it.